# Why do magnet/torrent links suddenly work when a remote service successfully resolves the same link?

Tags: bittorrent, magnet-links

Sometimes I try to download a torrent via a magnet link. Sometimes the client (ktorrent) doesn't respond to the magnet link. It just sits there without feedback.

I have noticed that if, after some time, I use a service such as magnet2torrent.com on the same magnet link to produce a downloadable `.torrent` file, my client then opens the torrent *twice*. It seems to be that it opens once from the magnet link and once from the `.torrent` file. This has happened a few times, *for torrents which have only recently been created.*

**My hypothesis** is that the magnet link fails to resolve in my local client but the client keeps trying, meanwhile a remove server independently resolves the same magnet link and then adds the torrent file to its cache before serving it; the successful resolution of the link in the remote server causes the same link to resolve on my local client.

1. Is my hypothesis correct?
2. Why should the server resolve the magnet link but not my client?
3. Why should the server's success enable my clients's success? What is the mechanim?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to occur on small swarms - test on some large torrent with many peers to get a comparison point.

It generally stems from connectivity problems where at least one party (you or the remote) is behind a NAT or firewall which means a connection cannot be established in one direction and you will have to wait until the other side picks up the information that there is someone in the swarm and then tries to connect from their end.